# Newbie App Engine Datastore question - Models and .filter()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am currently testing GAE and I am having some trouble adapting to the datastore ...

Given the example model:

```
  class Category(db.Model):
      name = db.StringProperty()
      date_time = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)

  class Link(db.Model): 
      category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category, collection_name='links')
      name = db.StringProperty()
      date_time = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
      link = db.LinkProperty()
      type = db.StringProperty(choices=set(["in", "out"]))
```

and the not working code:

```
category = Category.get(key)
link = category.links.filter('type=', 'in').get()
```

it seems that I am unable to filter() on the referenced property... 
Strange thing is that *category.links* is a Query object... 
It is possible to iterate through *category.links* and verify the *type* property but I am certain that there is a better way...

Any help is welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, just put a space between `type` and `=`

```
link = category.links.filter('type =', 'in').get()
```